vue rendering things on the center of my page?
My team and i were working on a web app, and we split to work faster
The thing is, when we tried to implement the best toolbar component, we took the code, and we paste it into our toolbar.component
Result of the page in friend's branch
And the other branch in the code results in this:
After implementing it in the develop branch
(The develop branch doesnt have the home section, thats why is all empty under the toolbar)
Here are the codes:
//The code of the toolbar.component: 

<script>
export default {
  name: "toolbar-component",
}
</script>

<template>
  <pv-toolbar class="toolbar">
    <template #start>
        <img src="../../assets/images/flexpal-logo.png" alt="Flex Pal Logo" style="width: 350px; height: 70px;"/>
    </template>
    <template #end>
      <ul class="list-none p-0 m-0 overflow-hidden" style="display:flex; ">
        <li>
          <Button>
            <a href="/home"> Home </a>
          </Button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Button>
            <a href="/routines"> Routines </a>
          </Button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Button>
            <a href="/nutrition"> Nutrition </a>
          </Button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Button>
            <a href="/book_section"> Book Session </a>
          </Button>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Button>
            <a href="/profile"> Profile </a>
          </Button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </template>
  </pv-toolbar>
</template>

<style scoped>
.toolbar{
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;

  li{
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
    Button{
      background-color: #6baada;
      border-radius: 10px;
      a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: white;
      }
    }

  }
}
</style>

// the main.js is the same in both branches:
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import './style.css'
import app1 from './app.vue'

import PrimeVue from "primevue/config";
import DialogService from "primevue/dialogservice";
import ConfirmationService from "primevue/confirmationservice";
import ToastService from "primevue/toastservice";

import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
import 'primevue/resources/primevue.min.css';
import 'primeflex/primeflex.css';
import router from "./router/index.js";

// Add UI Components for application
import Button       from "primevue/button";
import Card         from "primevue/card";
import SelectButton from "primevue/selectbutton";
import Sidebar      from "primevue/sidebar";
import Toolbar      from "primevue/toolbar";
import Calendar from 'primevue/calendar';
import Tag from "primevue/tag";
import InputText from 'primevue/inputtext';
import Menubar      from "primevue/menubar";
import Accordion from 'primevue/accordion';
import AccordionTab from 'primevue/accordiontab';
import Panel from 'primevue/panel';
import FloatLabel from 'primevue/floatlabel';
import Avatar from "primevue/avatar";
import Divider from "primevue/divider";

const app = createApp(app1);

app.use(PrimeVue, { ripple: true })
    .use(DialogService)
    .use(ConfirmationService)
    .use(ToastService)
    .component('Button', Button)
    .component('Card', Card)
    .component('pv-select-Button', SelectButton)
    .component('pv-sidebar', Sidebar)
    .component('Toolbar', Toolbar)
    .component('Calendar', Calendar)
    .component('Tag', Tag)
    .component('pv-InputText', InputText)
    .component('pv-button', Button)
    .component('Menubar', Menubar)
    .component('Accordion', Accordion)
    .component('AccordionTab', AccordionTab)
    .component('pv-floatLabel', FloatLabel)
    .component('pv-panel', Panel)
    .component('pv-toolbar', Toolbar)
    .component('pv-avatar', Avatar)
    .component('pv-divider', Divider)
    .use(router);
app.mount('#app');

// the app.vue is the same in both branches:
<script>
  import ToolbarComponent from "./public/components/toolbar.component.vue";

  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {ToolbarComponent},
    title: 'Flex Pal',
    data() {
      return {
        drawer: false,
        items: [
          { label: 'Routine List', to: '/routine-list'},
          { label: 'Plans', to: '/plans'},
          { label: 'Programming Session', to: '/programming-session'},
          { label: 'Home', to: '/home'},
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
    }
  }
</script>
<template>
  <toolbar-component></toolbar-component>
   <router-view/>
</template>
<style >
</style>

Our Styles.css is empty btw
We just copy pasted all the code (main.js, app.vue, toolbar.component, home.section, etc), and it is still rendering in the center, we could try doing another branch  starting from our partner's branch, but we want to understand the problem.
We appreciate the help.
We tried modifying the styles of each and one of the components, including the toolbar, removing the padding and all of that, but it doesn't work.

Can you add a fiddle/code-sandbox link or some reproducable example so that someone can try and check the same by running it?

The style issue must come from primevue css then. The only way is to add a fiddle/code-sandbox link here or try to debug and inspect the styles yourself in the browser devtools.

Agree with Ferry.  All styles, regardless of where they're being applied from, can be seen in the browser's DOM/element inspector and will tell you what stylesheet they originate from, which should help you track down where the style exists in your code or if it's from a library.  Have you tried debugging this at all in the browser?
